# Attachments in RavenDB

Tags: nosql, ravendb, attachment

What is the best way to handle attachments in RavenDB?

A webpage has an upload pdf button in addition to other fields. All those fields are saved into one document in ravendb.

Like wise, I also want the pdf the user uploads using the upload button to be saved somewhere...

How does RavenDB do something like this.. handling such attachment informtion...
Do I have to just store the path to the pdf file? or is there a way to store the entore pdf file itself?
Are there any examples I can see that have accomplished this ..

Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered here.
https://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/f4e8440cfd6ec6df/ac1b2334ebc04c6f?lnk=gst&q=pdf#ac1b2334ebc04c6f